# how to add data labels for bar graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

For example (code):

```
x = [3 6 2 9 5 1];
bar(x)
```

for this I need to add data labels on top of the each bar.
I know that I have to use TEXT keyword, but I'm not getting how to implement it.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/128396-how-do-i-label-the-bars-in-my-bar-graph-in-matlab

Comment: Yes Dan , I hv gone through that, my problem is:                                     1) they are using random data as input and my input is arrays.                                                                                                          2) i'm not getting wt value to use in place of 'y' co-ordinate while using TEXT keyword. (I'm new to matlab, plz guide me).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution with `text`:

```
x = [3 6 2 9 5 1];
bar(x)
ylim([0 max(x)*1.2])
text(1:numel(x),x+0.5,num2cell(x))
```

[image: data labels in bar]

Answer (score 0):

Based off [this answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/128396-how-do-i-label-the-bars-in-my-bar-graph-in-matlab):

```
data = [3 6 2 9 5 1];
figure; %// Create new figure
hbar = bar(data);    %// Create bar plot
%// Get the data for all the bars that were plotted
x = get(hbar,'XData');
y = get(hbar,'YData');
ygap = 0.1;  %// Specify vertical gap between the bar and label
ylimits = get(gca,'YLim');

%// The following two lines have minor tweaks from the original answer
set(gca,'YLim',[ylimits(1),ylimits(2)+0.2*max(y)]);
labels = cellstr(num2str(data'))                                   %//'

for i = 1:length(x) %// Loop over each bar
    xpos = x(i);        %// Set x position for the text label
    ypos = y(i) + ygap; %// Set y position, including gap
    htext = text(xpos,ypos,labels{i});          %// Add text label
    set(htext,'VerticalAlignment','bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment','center')
end
```

Comment: Thank u so much Dan, I made little change in ur code which suits my requirement... below is my code...

Comment: fileopn = '....';

A1 = xlsread(fileopn,'H247', 'E3:E21');
B1 = xlsread(fileopn,'H247', 'L3:L21');
C1 = xlsread(fileopn,'H247', 'S3:S21');

data = [A1 B1 C1];        then I continued ur code 4m figure....

Comment: im getting error as,                 Undefined function 'max' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in Untitled2 (line 46)
set(gca,'YLim',[ylimits(1),ylimits(2)+0.2*max(y)]);

Comment: @arjun So that's a completely different question. Where ever you are calling `max` is not in the code that is in your question nor in my answer. Google matlab cell arrays, try to solve the problem and if you can't then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts I have found the solution. Do the [following](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/129900-data-labels-above-bars-on-grouped-bar-plot#answer_137116):

```
y = Data;
for b = 1 : 10
    BarPlot(b) = bar(b, y(b), 'BarWidth', 0.9); % actual plot
    set(BarPlot(b), 'FaceColor', 'blue'); %Apply color
    barTopper = sprintf('%.1f%s', y(b)*100,'%'); % Place text on top
    text(b-0.5, y(b)+0.01, barTopper, 'FontSize', barFontSize); % position the text
    hold on;
end
```

Let me know if it works.